# How to add parameters to Jersey cypher rest api?

Tags: neo4j, jersey

I have an Neo4j RestAPI call like this:

```
        {
          "query" : "MATCH (x)-[r:friend]->(y) where y.name={yname} RETURN  x, y",

           "params" : {
            "yname" : "Jack"
          }
        }
```

This query works. Now I want to execute this query in Jersey Client:

```
       Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("neo4j", "test"));
        WebResource cypher = client.resource(SERVER_ROOT_URI + "cypher");
         String yname="Jack";
        String request = "{\"query\":\"MATCH (x)-[r:friend]->(y) where y.name={yname} RETURN  x, y\"}";

        ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypher.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
        cypherResponse.close();
```

How to represent the yname="Jack" in the above code so that the query will succeed?

Comment: What is error you get with this code ? Why are you not added the params part into your string request ?

Comment: @logisima, it works. Thanks.